# How to query a constexpr std::tuple at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, tuples

In C++0x, one can create a constexpr std::tuple, e.g. like

```
#include <tuple>
constexpr int i = 10;
constexpr float f = 2.4f;
constexpr double d = -10.4;
constexpr std::tuple<int, float, double> tup(i, f, d);
```

One also can query a std::tuple at runtime, e.g. via

```
int i2 = std::get<0>(tup);
```

But it is not possible to query it at compile time, e.g.,

```
constexpr int i2 = std::get<0>(tup);
```

will throw a compilation error (at least with the latest g++
snapshot 2011-02-19).

**Is there any other way to query a constexpr std::tuple at compile time?**

And if not, is there a conceptual reason why one is not supposed to query it?

(I am aware of avoiding using std::tuple, e.g., by using boost::mpl
or boost::fusion instead, but somehow it sounds wrong not to use the tuple class 
in the new standard...).

By the way, does anybody know why

```
  constexpr std::tuple<int, float, double> tup(i, f, d);
```

compiles fine, but

```
  constexpr std::tuple<int, float, double> tup(10, 2.4f, -10.4);
```

not?

Thanks a lot in advance!
- lars

Comment: In n3225.pdf, only the default constructor is marked constexpr. Perhaps it is just too early to use this feature?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::get` is not marked `constexpr`, so you cannot use it to retrieve the values from a `tuple` in a `constexpr` context, even if that tuple is itself `constexpr`.

Unfortunately, the implementation of `std::tuple` is opaque, so you cannot write your own accessors either.

Comment: Thanks. So your answer is "no, it is not possible." I had a look into <tuple> meanwhile and totally agree. This leaves the question: why cannot we query std::tuples at compile time? But evtl. this question is better discussed in the broader scope of my [question on constexpr of std::forward](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098069/why-discards-stdforward-constexpr-ness).

Comment: [N3305](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3305.html) proposes to add constexpr for `tuple::get`

Answer (score 4):

Now, std::get<> is a constexpr function. The following code compiles for me if I use gcc c++ 11 or above.

```
constexpr int i2 = std::get<0>(tup);
constexpr std::tuple<int, float, double> tup(10, 2.4f, -10.4);
```

Furthermore, you can generate a list of numbers at compile time by using make_index_sequence (c++14 or above) and access the tuple.

```
constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size<decltype(tup)>::value;
for_sequence(std::make_index_sequence<size>{}, [&](auto i){
        constexpr auto property = std::get<i>(tup);
        std::cout<<property<<std::endl;
});

template <typename T, T... S, typename F>
constexpr void for_sequence(std::integer_sequence<T, S...>, F&& f) {
    using unpack_t = int[];
    (void)unpack_t{(static_cast<void>(f(std::integral_constant<T, S>{})), 0)..., 0};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in c++17. But if you want to pass tuple into the constexpr function as a parameter, i would strongly recommend to read this post https://mpark.github.io/programming/2017/05/26/constexpr-function-parameters/

Answer (score -2):

I have not yet worked with C++0x, but it seems to me that std::get() is a function, rather than expression the compiler can directly interpret. As such, it has no meaning except at runtime, after the function itself has been compiled.

Comment: C++0x adds the keyword `constexpr` that actually forces the compiler to evaluate a function at compile time, i.e. with `constexpr int add(int x, int y) { return x+y;}` you can say `constexpr int i = add(7, 13);` and the value of i is available at compile time, e.g., in `static_assert(i == 20, "i correct");`. -- So my question is why is `std::get` not constexpr ?

Comment: The idea of `constexpr` is that the compiler can be told to calculate the result of a function call given that arguments are also const-expressions.

Comment: That's not my reading of the references I've found. My reading is that a constexpr can *define* an inline function returning a constant expression (replacing macros), but it can only *call* a function if that function is itself constexpr.

Comment: @Lars -- I suppose my guess would be, because std::get<T>(arg) is going to be used in situations where arg is not itself going to be a constexpr.

Comment: this would not be a problem either as constexpr will be discarded silently when called with non-constexpr arguments.