# Why does std::forward discard constexpr-ness?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

Being not declared `constexpr`, `std::forward` will discard constexpr-ness for any function it forwards arguments to. **Why is `std::forward` not declared `constexpr` itself so it can preserve constexpr-ness?**

Example: (tested with g++ snapshot-2011-02-19)

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T> constexpr int f(T x) { return -13;}
template <typename T> constexpr int g(T&& x) { return f(std::forward<T>(x));}

int main() {
  constexpr int j = f(3.5f);
  // next line does not compile: 
  // error: ‘constexpr int g(T&&) [with T = float]’ is not a constexpr function
  constexpr int j2 = g(3.5f);
}
```

Note: technically, it would be easy to make `std::forward` constexpr, e.g., like so (note that in g `std::forward` has been replaced by `fix::forward`):

```
#include <utility>

namespace fix {
  /// constexpr variant of forward, adapted from <utility>:
  template<typename Tp>
  inline constexpr Tp&&
  forward(typename std::remove_reference<Tp>::type& t) 
  { return static_cast<Tp&&>(t); }

  template<typename Tp>
  inline constexpr Tp&&
  forward(typename std::remove_reference<Tp>::type&& t) 
  {
    static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<Tp>::value, "template argument"
          " substituting Tp is an lvalue reference type");
    return static_cast<Tp&&>(t);
  }
} // namespace fix

template <typename T> constexpr int f(T x) { return -13;}
template <typename T> constexpr int g(T&& x) { return f(fix::forward<T>(x));}

int main() {
  constexpr int j = f(3.5f);
  // now compiles fine:
  constexpr int j2 = g(3.5f);
}
```

My question is: why is `std::forward` not defined like `fix::forward` ?

Note2: this question is somewhat related to my other [question about constexpr std::tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087364/how-to-query-a-constexpr-stdtuple-at-compile-time) as `std::forward` not being `constexpr` is the technical reason why `std::tuple` cannot be created by calling its cstr with rvalues, but this question here obviously is (much) more general.

Comment: quick note, identifiers beginning by `_[A-Z]` are reserved to the compiler implementers. Your program, as such, is ill-formed.

Comment: And _T is especially nasty if you should ever move to Windows, where it is a macro...

Comment: @Matthieu M, @Bo Persson Thanks. I replaced all names _T by T etc. so others can try the code more safely / easily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The general answer is that the C++ committee's Library Working Group have not done an exhaustive trawl through the working draft looking for opportunities to use the new core facilities. These features have been used where people have had the time and inclination to look at possible uses, but there is not the time for exhaustive checking.

There are some papers regarding additional uses of `constexpr` in the works, such as those in the [November 2010 mailing](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/#mailing2010-11).

Comment: Thanks. I knew the related document [N3231](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3231.html) already, but it does not mention section 20.3.3 on std::forward. -- What you provide is more a "social reason". I am interested in a "conceptual reason", i.e., is there anything wrong in making std::forward constexpr or would it be fine?

Comment: I can't see any reason why not at first glance.

Comment: With issue reports for making it possible to pass and call function pointers in constexpr functions (and literal function object types can be constexpr already), having std::forward be non-constexpr seems unfortunate.

Comment: [N3305](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3305.html) proposes to add constexpr for `std::forward`