# What is the purpose of std::common_type?

Tags: c++, c++11

I started looking at `std::common_type` and am not exactly sure about its purpose and its functionality.
A few things still strike me as odd:

- Order of arguments is important: `common_type<Foo, Bar, Baz>` might be different from `common_type<Baz, Foo, Bar>`. Either might compile, the other might not. While this is clear from the way `common_type` is defined, it feels strange and unintuitive. Is this for lack of a universal solution or intended?
- Instantiation can result in a compiler error instead of something I can handle. How to check if `common_type` will actually compile? `is_convertible` is not enough as `common_type` might be specialized?
- There is still no way to figure out the common type in a situation like this:

  ```
  struct Baz;
  struct Bar { int m; };
  struct Foo { int m; }; 
  struct Baz { Baz(const Bar&); Baz(const Foo&); };
  ```

  The recommended solution would be to specialize `common_type` which is tedious. Is there a better solution?

For reference see §20.9.7.6 Table 57 in N3242.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`std::common_type` was introduced for use with `std::duration` --- if you add a `std::duration<int>` and a `std::duration<short>` then the result should be `std::duration<int>`. Rather than specifying an endless stream of allowed pairings, the decision was made to delegate to a separate template which found the result using the core language rules applicable to the `?:` arithmetic-if operator.

People then saw that this template might be generally useful, and it was added as `std::common_type`, and extended to handle an arbitrary number of types. In the C++0x library it is only used for pairs of types though.

You should be able to use the new SFINAE rules to detect whether or not some instantiation of `std::common_type` is valid. I haven't tried though. In most cases if there isn't a "common type" then there isn't anything meaningful you can do anyway, so a compile error is reasonable.

`std::common_type` is not magic --- it follows the rules of `?:`. If `true?a:b` will compile, `std::common_type<decltype(a),decltype(b)>::type` will give you the type of the result.

Comment: Can you provide a link, reference or example to the new SFINAE rules? Also, any ideas on my last point? I do understand why `common_type` isn't able to produce an answer to `common_type<Bar, Foo>` still I would find it useful and intuitive.

Comment: SFINAE is described in 14.8.2, especially paragraphs 5-8. It's not particularly clear, but "if substitution results in an invalid type or expression, type deduction fails" from paragraph 8 is a key part. Basically, if you write a function template that depends on `common_type<A,B>::type` being available, where at least one of `A` and `B` are template parameters of that function template then that function is not considered for overload resolution of `common_type<A,B>::type` is not valid. If you provide an alternative overload of the function then that will be chosen instead.

Comment: If you want `common_type<Bar,Foo>::type` to yield `Baz` then you must specialize `common_type` yourself. Otherwise, how can the compiler know which of the many types that can be constructed from both `Foo` and `Bar` to use? e.g. `boost::any` can be constructed from anything at all.

Comment: Ah, that the resolution could be ambiguous didn't occur to me. I haven't managed to get SFINAE working with `common_type` though. An example is here: http://pastebin.com/UiEKNRzL But I'll open a new question after closer examination.

Comment: Upvoted.  And I'll add:  `common_type` is more of a library builder's tool, than a library user's tool.  The library user typically uses `common_type` only if the library author has designed `common_type` into his library's interface.  The library author can choose to use `common_type` or not, depending on whether `common_type` is actually useful for his library or not.

Comment: @Howard Updating a library to use `common_type` is actually what I'm trying to achieve. Although I try to keep some legacy functionality which offered features like `common_type<A,B>` when there is no such type.

Comment: For C++03, my emulation can be used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426330/uses-of-a-c-arithmetic-promotion-header/2450157#2450157 . It has a drawback though: Won't work with references/lvalues!

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few use cases of `std::common_type`:

### 1. *sum* of variadic pack

Here is [a version for variadic sum](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e11d21216453190f) that needs `common_type`:

```
template<typename... T>
constexpr auto sum(T&&... values) {
    std::common_type_t<T...> sum {}; // <= here we need std::common_type
    // see code in the link above for the machinery of the below code
    static_for<sizeof...(T)>([&](auto index) {
        sum += get<index>(values...);
    });
    return sum;
}
```

Above example is using machinery from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37836252/2085626) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59954211/2085626) SO posts.

---

***A note:*** you can achieve the same with [the following code](https://godbolt.org/z/rgNKAY) without the need for `common_type`:

```
template<typename T>
auto sum(T&& t) {
    return t;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
auto sum(T&& t, Ts&&... ts) {
    return t + sum(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
}
```

---

### 2. requiring variadic pack *to have a common type*

[Code below](https://godbolt.org/z/RTWr_1) is based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61483494/2085626).

```
template <typename AlwaysVoid, typename... Ts>
struct has_common_type_impl : std::false_type {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct has_common_type_impl<std::void_t<std::common_type_t<Ts...>>, Ts...>
    : std::true_type {};

template <typename... Ts>
concept has_common_type = 
    sizeof...(Ts) < 2 ||
    has_common_type_impl<void, Ts...>::value;

template<typename... Ts> requires has_common_type<Ts...>
void foo(Ts&&... ts) {}
```

---

### 3. *make_array* from variadic pack

There was a [pending proposal for the function *make_array*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array). For a discussion if there still a need for *make_array* see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942556/current-status-of-stdmake-array).

A simple implementation of `make_array` would look [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/CE627Y):

```
template<typename... T>
constexpr auto make_array(T&&... values) requires has_common_type<T...> {
    using TYPE = std::common_type_t<std::decay_t<T>...>;
    return std::array<TYPE, sizeof...(T)>{static_cast<TYPE>(values)...};
}
```

with the following usage examples:

```
constexpr auto arr1 = make_array(1, 2, 3);
constexpr auto arr2 = make_array(1, 2.5, 3);
using namespace std::string_literals;
auto arr3 = make_array("hello"s, "world");
```

Note that the proposal for `make_array` had an option to provide the actual requested type, but in case it is not provided then the `common_type` is to be used.