# Are there any active proposals to change integral promotion rules?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, integer-promotion

As already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15211463/6205379) integral promotion rules can cause headaches in some cases (especially for arithmetic operations between signed and unsigned types). At the end of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15388973/6205379) answer there is a link to a proposal. However that proposal is from 2012 and I don't know if it was even submitted.

Are there any active proposals or plans to change integral promotion rules to something like *the next higher ranked signed type that can hold the value range of the promoted type*? I know this causes inconsistency as `unsigned long long` cannot be promoted to any higher ranked type. This isn't a perfect solution but wouldn't it be at least better than the current situation?

Comment: I'm kinda tempted to say this can be a dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175977/how-to-track-newer-c-std-documents-of-given-topic

Comment: I personally would prefer that all the implicit conversions were deprecated and then removed from the language, however something like this is definitely not going to happen.

Comment: Per [this](https://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-status.html) the issue is still open

Comment: @VTT How would this play along with minimum type must be `int` for arithmetic operatrions?

Comment: I think this is an atavism inherited directly from B (or even from BCPL) that had only a single "cell" type. I don't see any reason not to make arithmetic operations yield the same type as operands and not to have routines to handle overflow.

Comment: Note that the proposal that the answer links to is only about overload resolution. It wouldn't change any promotion rules.

Comment: @VTT note the [rationale for promotion rules as they are can be found in the C99 rationale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24372323/1708801)