# How to check the type of passed arguments to variadic function

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

I'm new to variadic templates and for the sake of learning consider the following function

```
template <typename T, typename... args>
T* make_arr(args... arg) {

   // Code to check if passed args are of the same type

   T* arr = new T[sizeof...(arg)]{ arg... };
   return arr;
}
```

I have two questions:

1. I want the function to be templated and I want the passed arguments to be of the same type so the question: is it possible to check if passed arguments are of the same type ?
2. Is it possible to deduce the type of the array pointer by deducing the type of `args...`, I mean without using `<typename T>`? ... I used decltype(arg) but it didnt work ...

Note: please edit the title question if it is not appropriate ... thanks

Comment: not sure, but did you try `typeid` function.

Comment: You want the `args` to be the same type *as each other*, and potentially different from `T`? Or you want them all to be the same type as `T`? Or you allow them to be different from each other, but simply require that it be possible to build your array of `T` with types that can convert to `T`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I found is to make a helper function using SFINAE

```
//Basic function
template<typename T>
void allsame(T) {}

//Recursive function
template<typename T, typename T2, typename... Ts, 
typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, T2>::value>>
void allsame(T arg, T2 arg2, Ts... args)
{
    allsame(arg2, args...);
}
```

You can then call it like so:

```
allsame(arg...);
```

The compiler will then throw an error if the types are not the same.

---

For 2), you could modfiy `allsame` to return the type. The only drawback to this function is that it won't work if the type isn't default constructable.

```
template<typename T>
T allsame(T) { return{}; }

T allsame(T arg, T2 arg2, Ts... args)
```

Then, you can `decltype(allsame(args...))` to get the type

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you'll need these includes:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
```

then, let us declare variadic template to detect whether types are same or not:

```
template <typename ... args>
struct all_same : public std::false_type {};


template <typename T>
struct all_same<T> : public std::true_type {};


template <typename T, typename ... args>
struct all_same<T, T, args...> : public all_same<T, args ... > {};
```

now we can use `static_assert` to detect if parameters types are same:

```
template <typename T, typename... args>
T* make_arr(args... arg) {

   // Code to check if passed args are of the same type
   static_assert(all_same<args ...>::value, "Params must have same types");

   T* arr = new T[sizeof...(arg)]{ arg... };
   return arr;
};
```

Finally, let us take return type of your function as first type of parameters - if all types are same we can take any of them. We use `std::tuple` for this

```
template <typename... args>
typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<args...> >::type * make_arr(args... arg) {

   // Code to check if passed args are of the same type
   static_assert(all_same<args ...>::value, "Params must have same types");

   typedef typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<args...> >::type T;

   T* arr = new T[sizeof...(arg)]{ arg... };
   return arr;
};
```

Comment: This does work but I didnt understand the last part of your answer which is the tuple part ... If you can briefly simplify it, I would be grateful ... +1 anyway

Comment: @Leo `std::tuple` is a standard variadic template, like `std::pair`, but with arbitrary types list. And there is `std::tuple_element` helper template which can be used for access to a tuple field or to type of tuple field by its index. In our case `std::tuple<args.. >` represents list of template types, and we take type at index 0 using `std::tuple_element<...>::type`. As far templates arguments has same types any of that we can use as type to make pointer for holding array.

Answer (score 2):

Start with a `constexpr bool` function to check if all the booleans are true. This will be useful when checking that all the `is_same` calls are `true`.

```
constexpr bool all() {
    return true;
}
template<typename ...B>
constexpr bool all(bool b, B... bs) {
    return b && all(bs...);
}
```

Anyway, here is the `make_arr` function:

```
template <typename... args
, class ...
, typename T = std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<args...>>
, typename = std::enable_if_t< all(std::is_same<T, args>{}...) >
>
T* make_arr(args&&... arg) {
    static_assert( all(std::is_same<T, args>{}...) ,"");
    T* arr = new T[sizeof...(arg)]{ std::forward<args>(arg)... };
    return arr;
}
```

A few comments:

- perfect-forwarding is used, `&&` and `std::forward`, to avoid potential copies if your type is large.
- the type of the first argument is extracted [by creating a `std::tuple` type and using `std::tuple_element<0, ..>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162903/template-parameter-packs-access-nth-type-and-nth-element).
- a `static_assert` is used, where each type is compared to the first type (via `is_same`).
- I guess you want SFINAE to 'hide' this function unless the types are all identical. This is achieved via `typename = std::enable_if_t< ..boolean-expression.. >`
- the `class ...` is essentially redundant. It's only purpose is to make it impossible for developers to cheat the checks by manually specifying the types (`make_arr<int,char,size_t,bool>(..)`). However, maybe this is too conservative - the `static_assert` will catch them anyway!