# Get item by index from boost::variant like it's possible with std::variant

Tags: c++, boost, variant, boost-variant

With `std::variant<int, bool>` I can call `std::get<0>(var)` to get the value in the variant as it's first type - `int`.

How can I do this with `boost::variant`? `boost::get<>` seems to support only getting by type and not by index and I find the documentation very difficult to understand.

Comment: Looks like you can't.

Comment: @BaummitAugen and is there a way to hack it? perhaps with some mpl shenanigans?

Comment: Most likely yes. What standard?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I use the (almost) latest of compilers - only emscripten is making me lagg behind - it's version of libcxx doesn't have ```<variant>``` yet... so C++14 (also latest boost)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be not included in boost.

However, with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29753388/3002139), we can simply role our own:

```
template<int N, typename... Ts> using NthTypeOf =
        typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;

template<int N, typename... Ts>
auto &get(boost::variant<Ts...> &v) {
    using target = NthTypeOf<N, Ts...>;
    return boost::get<target>(v);
}

template<int N, typename... Ts>
auto &get(const boost::variant<Ts...> &v) {
    using target = NthTypeOf<N, Ts...>;
    return boost::get<target>(v);
}

int main () {
    boost::variant<int, double> v = 3.2;
    std::cout << get<1>(v);
}
```

See it [live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Q6EjjI4HsgR0asIO).

The pointer overloads can of course be added analogously if desired.

Comment: yeah my bad - the const-ness got propagated properly by just using auto. Thanks for the answer! IMHO this needs to be added to ```boost::variant```...

Comment: @onqtam Never tried contributing, but I guess you could submit a patch. Don't see why they would be against having it. (Not sure what standard they use though, in C++11, this already gets slightly more ugly and I'm not sure how to do it in C++03.)

Comment: @onqtam it is my firm view that access by index, when you have access by type available, is an utter anti-pattern.

Comment: @RichardHodges, in a dynamic environment, the `index()` (`which()` in boost) and `get()` are very useful.