# How can I bubble last element in the variadic templates?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have template function that get variadic templates as (for example) as `(int, int, double)`

```
template<class... Arg>
void
bubble(const Arg &...arg)
{ another_function(arg...); }
```

Inside the function, I must call with a different order of parameters `(double, int, int)`. How can I implement this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162903/template-parameter-packs-access-nth-type-and-nth-element might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `std::index_sequence`, you may do something like:

```
template <typename Tuple, std::size_t ... Is>
decltype(auto) bubble_impl(const Tuple& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    constexpr auto size = sizeof...(Is);
    return another_function(std::get<(Is + size - 1) % size>(tuple)...);
}


template <class... Args>
decltype(auto) bubble(const Args &...args)
{
    return bubble_impl(std::tie(args...), std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have one more question. How to change this code if another_function has returned value(int)?

Comment: @Hait: Simply by adding return type and return :)