Get templated struct without knowing initial template arguments
I am looking for a way to get a specified templated struct from the custom Node classes I am building without having to static_cast or dynamic_cast when I get the pointers. What ways can I use to avoid that?
node.hpp
#pragma once

#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#ifndef DATA_TEMPLATE
#define DATA_TEMPLATE template<typename T>
#else
#define DATA_TEMPLATE
#endif

#ifndef FUNCTION_TEMPLATE
#define FUNCTION_TEMPLATE template<typename R, typename... T>
#else
#define FUNCTION_TEMPLATE
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <ostream>
#include <memory>

struct Node {
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;

    Node(Node* prev = nullptr, Node* next = nullptr) : prev(prev), next(next) {}

    ~Node() = default;
    Node* getNext() const { return next; }
    void setNext(Node* next) { this->next = next; }
    Node* getPrev() const { return prev; }
    void setPrev(Node* prev) { this->prev = prev; }

    virtual void print(std::ostream& os) const = 0;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Node& node) { node.print(os); return os; }
};

DATA_TEMPLATE
struct DataNode : public Node {
    T data;

    DataNode(Node* prev, T dat, Node* next) : Node{ prev, next }, data(dat) {}
    DataNode(Node* prev, T dat) : DataNode{ prev, dat, nullptr } {}
    DataNode(T dat, Node* next) : DataNode{ nullptr, dat, next } {}
    DataNode(T dat) : DataNode{ nullptr, dat, nullptr } {}


    T getData() { return data; }
    void setData(T newData) { data = newData; }

    void print(std::ostream& os) const override { os << data; }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const DataNode<T>& node) { node.print(os); return os; };
};

FUNCTION_TEMPLATE
struct FunctionNode : public Node {
    std::function<R(T...)> fn;

    FunctionNode(Node* prev, std::function<R(T...)> func, Node* next) : Node{ prev, next }, fn(func) {}
    FunctionNode(Node* prev, std::function<R(T...)> func) : FunctionNode{ prev, func, nullptr } {}
    FunctionNode(std::function<R(T...)> func, Node* next) : FunctionNode{ nullptr, func, next } {}
    FunctionNode(std::function<R(T...)> func) : FunctionNode{ nullptr, func, nullptr } {}

    void print(std::ostream& os) const override { os << "FunctionNode(" << fn.target_type().name() << ")"; }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const FunctionNode& node) { node.print(os); return os; }

    R operator()(T... args) { return fn(args...); }
};

#endif

main.cpp
// Includes ...

int main()
{
    DataNode<int> node{
        new DataNode<int>{ 7 },
        3,
        new DataNode<int>{ 5 }
    };

    std::cout << node << std::endl;
    

    auto* prevNode = node.getPrev();
    auto* nextNode = node.getNext();

    std::cout << *prevNode << std::endl;
    std::cout << *nextNode << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

I want a function Node to output its result. Example:
// Includes ...

int main()
{
    DataNode<int> node{
        new DataNode<int>{ 7 },
        3,
        new FunctionNode<int, int, int>(add) // add implemented elsewhere
    };

    std::cout << node << std::endl;
    

    auto* prevNode = node.getPrev();
    auto* nextNode = node.getNext(); // Should be a FunctionNode

    std::cout << *prevNode << std::endl;
    std::cout << (*nextNode)(2, 4) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Expected Output:
3
7
6

Edit: I am using the ISO C++ 20 Language Standard
Edit 2: Fixed the operation for the DataNode, can't seem to figure out running the FunctionNode.

This is too much code for a [mre]. Can you remove all unrelated code parts?

Note that FunctionNode is an abstract class (it lacks the implementation of the pure virtual function print) and thus cannot be instantiated. You can be sure that every Node* pointer does in fact point to some instantiation of DataNode

Why did you provide operator<< imlementation for DataNode specifically, and not for  Node? There's a print method in Node - I assume the point of that is to allow any Node, of any dervied type, to be printed. If you provide operator<<(std::ostream&, const Node&), then you can just write std::cout << *prevNode (note the star; std::cout << prevNode without the star prints the address  of the node, not the node itself).

If you want to actually arrange the nodes into a doubly-linked list as the naming implies (and not into a tree as it currently is in your example), then I believe this is not possible. If you actually want a tree, you can parametrize the base node type with the types of child nodes.

Assuming I have understood the question correctly, it could be substantially improved with a more precise title.  I suggest: "How can I get the exact type at compile time of a node in a heterogeneous linked list?"

Restating the goal
As I understand the question, the main point is you want the line:
    auto* nextNode = node.getNext(); // Should be a FunctionNode

to deduce that nextNode has type FunctionNode<int,int,int>*.
Why that does not work now
In the current code, nextNode will instead be deduced to have type
Node* because that is the return type of Node::getNext().
Consequently, a type cast is required (and what is what we want to
avoid).
The fact that the immediately preceding lines of code manifestly
populated the next field with a pointer to a
FunctionNode<int,int,int> is of no consequence; the C++ languages
rules only take into account the type of node on the line in question.
Heterogeneous recursive data type
The core issue is you want to create a statically-typed heterogeneous
recursive data type.  That is, Node is recursive because its type
refers to itself (it contains a pointer to a Node), and heterogeneous
because you want the data at each node to be potentially different.  And
you're asking that it be statically typed, meaning the compiler already
knows the type at every level, rather than having to use a type cast to
retrieve the proper type at the proper level.
To do this, create an interior node class template that accepts both the
type of the stored data and the types of all of its children, and their
children, and so on.  This is inconvenient at best, but is the only way
for the compiler to know what the type of the data will be at every
level.
Here is an example showing a singly-linked list of int and float:
#include <iostream>

template <typename DATA>
struct Node {
  DATA m_data;

  Node(DATA const &data) : m_data(data) {}
};

template <typename DATA, typename CHILD>
struct InteriorNode : Node<DATA> {
  CHILD *m_child;

  InteriorNode(DATA data, CHILD *child)
    : Node<DATA>(data),
      m_child(child)
  {}
};

int main()
{
  // The type has to encode the data types at all levels, and therefore
  // the shape of the entire tree.
  InteriorNode<int, Node<float> > tree{
    5,
    new Node<float>{
      3.14
    }
  };

  // The fields have the proper types.
  std::cout << tree.m_data << "\n";
  std::cout << tree.m_child->m_data << "\n";
  return 0;
}

Output:
5
3.14

The extension to a binary tree is straightforward, as is use with other
types (including function types).
Doubly-linked list
However, the names next and prev in the example suggest that the
intent is to create a doubly-linked list.  The approach in the example
above will not work for that, but it could be done using variadic
templates, using an integer index to say which element in the parameter
pack each node contains.
Example:
#include <cassert>           // assert
#include <iostream>          // std::cout
#include <tuple>             // std::{tuple, tuple_element, ...}


// Get element `index` of `Ts`.
//
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162903/template-parameter-packs-access-nth-type-and-nth-element
template <int index, typename... Ts>
using NthTypeOfPack =
  typename std::tuple_element<index, std::tuple<Ts...> >::type;

// Get the number of elements in `Ts`.
template <typename... Ts>
inline constexpr int packSize = std::tuple_size_v<std::tuple<Ts...> >;


// Has member `type` that equals `THEN` if `b` is true, `ELSE` otherwise.
template <bool b,
          typename THEN,
          typename ELSE>
struct ITE;

template <typename THEN,
          typename ELSE>
struct ITE<true, THEN, ELSE> {
  using type = THEN;
};

template <typename THEN,
          typename ELSE>
struct ITE<false, THEN, ELSE> {
  using type = ELSE;
};


// Statically typed heterogeneous doubly-linked list.
//
// `index` indicates which element of `DATAs` this node has.
//
template <int index,
          typename... DATAs>
struct Node {
public:      // types
  using MyData = NthTypeOfPack<index, DATAs...>;

  using PrevNode =
    typename ITE<(index > 0),
                 Node<index-1, DATAs...>,
                 void>                           ::type;

  using NextNode =
    typename ITE<(index+1 < packSize<DATAs...>),
                 Node<index+1, DATAs...>,
                 void>                           ::type;

public:      // data
  MyData m_data;
  PrevNode *m_prev;
  NextNode *m_next;

public:      // methods
  Node(MyData data, NextNode *next = nullptr)
    : m_data(data),
      m_prev(nullptr),
      m_next(next)
  {
    // We need `if constexpr` because the code inside it will not
    // compile when `index+1` equals the pack size.
    if constexpr (index+1 < packSize<DATAs...>) {
      if (m_next) {
        m_next->m_prev = this;
      }
    }
  }
};


int main()
{
  Node<0, int, float, char> list{
    5,
    new Node<1, int, float, char>{
      3.14,
      new Node<2, int, float, char>{
        'x'
      }
    }
  };

  // The data fields have the proper types.
  std::cout << list.m_data << "\n";
  std::cout << list.m_next->m_data << "\n";
  std::cout << list.m_next->m_next->m_data << "\n";

  // Check the list links.
  assert(list.m_prev == nullptr);
  assert(list.m_next->m_prev == &list);
  assert(list.m_next->m_next->m_prev == list.m_next);
  assert(list.m_next->m_next->m_next == nullptr);

  // NOTE: The memory for the second and third list elements is leaked!

  return 0;
}

Output:
5
3.14
x

I don't recommend actually using this design since it seems very
inconvenient.  But it is, I think, an answer to the question.
