How to interleave C++ template parameter packs
I have this c++ template function
template <int N, int B, auto... Args>
void somefunc() {
    // do work...
}

, which I can call like this:
somefunc<1, true, 2, false>();

I want to expand the API so that clients can call somefunc like this as well:
somefunc<Pack<1, true>, Pack<2, false>>(); // equivalent to somefunc<1, true, 2, false>()

, where Pack is some struct:
template <int N, bool B>
struct Pack
{
    static constexpr int value = N;
    static constexpr int flag = B;
};

A straightforward approach would be to try something like this:
template <typename... Packs>
void somefunc() {
    somefunc<Packs::value..., Packs::flag...>();
}

But this expands to:
somefunc<1, 2, true, false>();

instead of to:
somefunc<1, true, 2, false>();

Is there a simple way to expand the API in the way described?

I write libraries, and I think your main goal should be to make use as friendly as possible.  And that does not include showing all the template arguments to your clients. Which means you don't have to "prettify" them first.  <1,true> is also semantically very weak, WHAT is the client chosing here? (could be an artifact of your MRE)>. Same for just using an int instead of an enum (what are valid values). ... so I got so many questions, which probably means it is not clear WHAT you want to model. So maybe the real question is "I want to model XYZ", how can I do that using templates?

@PepijnKramer In my use case, all template arguments need to be explicitly set by the client. But that is not the point. I do not want to get into discussion about API, this is a pure technical issue. I want to enable calling somefunc in the two ways as I described. I just want to know what is the simplest way to make that possible.

I would go the reverse way if you have to provide both API, Pack is the clean way

@Jarod42 Ok, how to do it in reversed way? The problem is the same. Please, do not focus on the API, I want to know the technical aspect of doing this.

To flatten Packs, you might use std::tuple:
template <typename... Packs>
void somefunc() {
    constexpr std::tuple t = std::tuple_cat(std::tuple{Packs::value, Packs::flag}...);
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        return somefunc<std::get<Is>(t)...>();
    }(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(t)>>());
}

Demo
or with std::apply
which requires to wrap constants into std::integral_constant as regular function parameters are not constexpr.
template <typename... Packs>
void somefunc() {
    constexpr std::tuple t =
        std::tuple_cat(std::tuple{std::integral_constant<int, Packs::value>{},
                                  std::integral_constant<int, Packs::flag>{}}...);
    return std::apply([](auto... args){ somefunc<args()...>(); }, t);
}

Demo

Thank you, that is what I needed.
Out of curiosity, would it be possible to do it without std::tuple and std::index_sequence. This seems rather complicated for a simple goal. I know c++ is often that way, but I wonder how hard would it be to do it without standard library, for example. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Also, I suggest using std::tuple_size_v instead of sizeof...(Packs) * 2>

As std::tuple/std::index_sequence are implementable, you can do it without std. But I don't see a simpler way... Unless somefunc<Packs...>(); is equivalent to (somefunc<Packs>(), ...);.

Here is a possible solution but note that it works only for two int in the Pack structure.
The idea is to first build a compile-time array holding the interleaved values that can then be sent as template parameters to the target function.
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>

template <int N, int B, auto... Args>
void somefunc() 
{
    // do work...
    std::cout << N << " " << B << "\n";
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Args)>0)   { somefunc<Args...>();  }
}


// see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162903/template-parameter-packs-access-nth-type-and-nth-element
template<int N, typename... Ts> using NthTypeOf = typename std::tuple_element_t<N, std::tuple<Ts...>>;

template <typename... Packs>
void somefunc() 
{
    constexpr int N = 2*sizeof...(Packs);
    
    // First, we build an array holding the interleaved values
    constexpr auto arr = [&]<std::size_t...Is> (std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return std::array<int, N>{ { (Is%2==0 ? NthTypeOf<Is/2,Packs...>::value : NthTypeOf<Is/2,Packs...>::flag )... }};
    } (std::make_index_sequence<N>());
    
    // Then we call the function with the array content. 
    [&]<std::size_t...Is> (std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        somefunc <arr[Is]...>();
    } (std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

template <int N, bool B>
struct Pack
{
    static constexpr int value = N;
    static constexpr int flag  = B;
};

int main()
{
    somefunc<Pack<1, true>, Pack<2, false>, Pack<3, true>>();
}

Demo here

"that it works only for two int in the Pack structure" Using tuple allows to bypass this restriction

@Jarod42, yes indeed, I have just seen your answer
