# Transparent constexpr int as type id

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a struct `Foo`.
I would like to add some kind of id (placeholder ?) to statically select from a tuple of values passed to different `Foo` objects.
Ideally I would not make it a template type because it will trigger many changes in other locations.

[I tried adding an integer to it and use constexpr expressions (Demo)](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3LZ0Fe%2421)

```
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
private:
  const int pl;

public:
  constexpr Foo (int c) : pl(c) {}

  constexpr int place() {return pl;}

  template <typename... T>
  constexpr int extract(std::tuple<T ...> const &vals) {
    // I would like to uncomment the following but it fails compiling
    // return std::get<pl>(vals);
    return std::get<0>(vals);
  }
};

int main(void) {
   constexpr Foo f(1);
   constexpr std::tuple<int, int> test = std::make_tuple(0, 10);

   // The following passes
   static_assert(f.place() == 1, "ERROR");
   // The following fails
   static_assert(f.extract(test) == 10, "ERROR");
}
```

I was expecting that I could use the `constexpr place()` in the `get<>`, what am I missing?

Do I have a way out without using templates?

Comment: Since `std::get` isn't `constexpr`, I suspect this won't work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087364/how-to-query-a-constexpr-stdtuple-at-compile-time

Comment: You're right, as Dave Abrahams says there: "N3305 proposes to add constexpr for tuple::get". Do I have a workaround ? I can go for something else than tuples but I don't really know what atm.

Comment: Your member functions ought to be `const` as well.

Comment: What exactly is your goal?  You cannot pass `Foo` by value or reference into a function and then use it to generate a different type when you call `extract`.  Now, if you have a bounded set of types in your tuple, it isn't hard to take a run time `int` and auto-write a `switch` that takes either a single multi-type functor or a list of functors that act on each of the types out of the `tuple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first blocker is that [std::get](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) isn't `constexpr`, so even if `std::get<0>` works for you, it doesn't have to. (Credit to @Nate Kohl)

You can try hard and write your own `tuple` with `constexpr` accessor, but this approach will fail too. *Every* function that is `constexpr` also *must* be callable without a `constexpr` argument (or constexpr this). There is currently no way to overload on constexpr.

So, bad luck. This is impossible in C++11.

Comment: Well, in my particular case, I am interested in the type of Foo more than the instance. Here is a solution that works but that is going to be nasty to implement int my bigger codebase (http://liveworkspace.org/code/aoBwa$3)

Comment: I can't think of a nicer way to do that. Sorry.

Comment: @NickV: (http://liveworkspace.org/code/3uEri9) `std::make_tuple` is not `constexpr`

Comment: @rici: Good catch, thanks. I was relying on the static_assert but it seems it isn't a guarantee of constexpr-ness by itself.